# putting 8 image borders using positioning inside a div

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

[image: Visual]

I'm trying to put *image borders* in all corners of a `<div>`. All **red** boxes are fixed; **yellow** boxes will repeat, and I've been playing with `relative` and `absolute` positioning - not sure of any other way. I have purposely created all the elements needed, I just need help on the logic.

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/pedenski/snLGs/

I'd really appreciate if you could assist me on this. Thanks.

```
SIDE BORDER ----------------------------------------

tb = top border  (http://i50.tinypic.com/2ufua6r.gif)
lb = left border (http://i47.tinypic.com/24wr05d.gif)
rb = rightborder (http://i50.tinypic.com/3307521.gif)
bb = bottom border = (http://i45.tinypic.com/2gvsjfd.gif)

EDGE BORDER --------------------------------------------

tlc = top left corner (http://i45.tinypic.com/fxyvlc.gif)
trc = top right corner (http://i46.tinypic.com/5c10km.jpg)
blc = bottom left corner (http://i47.tinypic.com/jptv7q.gif)
brc = bottom right corner (http://i50.tinypic.com/1shc03.gif)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that, you have completely forgotten about the end `</div>` tags. And another thing is, yes, using `ID` here is good, but use classes for all as you have almost same characters, except `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` values. Since the corners are of fixed width, you can consider using sprites.

#### CSS

```
.eb {
    height: 16px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

#tlc {
    background-image: url(http://i45.tinypic.com/fxyvlc.gif);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#trc {
    background-image: url(http://i46.tinypic.com/5c10km.jpg);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

#blc {
    background-image: url(http://i47.tinypic.com/jptv7q.gif);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#brc {
    background-image: url(http://i50.tinypic.com/1shc03.gif);
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.sb {
    position: absolute;
}

#tb {
    background: url("http://i50.tinypic.com/2ufua6r.gif") repeat-x;
    top: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 255px;
}
#lb {
    background: url("http://i47.tinypic.com/24wr05d.gif") repeat-y;
    left: 0;
    height: 255px;
    width: 20px;
}
#rb {
    background: url("http://i50.tinypic.com/3307521.gif") repeat-y;
    right: 0;
    height: 255px;
    width: 20px;
}
#bb {
    background: url("http://i45.tinypic.com/2gvsjfd.gif") repeat-x;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 16px;
    width: 255px;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FK2jw/

Comment: thank you. i have learned so much in your reply. it never occur to me to use id/class at the same time. This will surely change how i code. thanks again.

Comment: Sure, and if you are willing to learn, please go through the good practices of CSS / HTML. Also, twitter bootstrap is a better way for you to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think tou need to re-think your approach, and use background images, instead of positioned divs. Here's an article on how to do this: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200406/flexible_box_with_custom_corners_and_borders/

I would just use border-radius in CSS, though: http://border-radius.com/